# div contents disalign when change window size

Tags: html

below is the sample of my websites navigation div
when i reduce the size of the window the other links gets on next line instead of being fixed to therir postion.here is the cose and css.

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>test page</title>    
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id=navigation>
<ul id="navigation-bar">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="popup.htm">Images</a></li>
  <li><a href="softwares.html">Softwares</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <br><br>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the css

```
div#navigation {
width:100%;
background-color:#000;
border-top:2px solid #5d6869;
border-bottom:2px solid #5d6869;
}

#navigation-bar {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

#navigation-bar li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

#navigation-bar li a {
  padding: 0em 1em 0.08em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:1.8em;
}

#navigation-bar li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  background:#5d6869;
}
```

can anyone help me whats the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `li` elements are floated left. Floated elements, when the parent's width is not wide enough to fit, automatically move to the next line. It's their built in behavior

If you want them to stay on the same line and be hidden when the parent is not wide enough, you can give them `display:inline-block` and give the parent a set height, say `height:35px;`, and also give the parent `overflow:hidden;`

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qztEr/) of that approach

**EDIT** based on your comment below

In that case, give the parent a `min-width`. [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qztEr/4/)

Comment: i dont want it to be hide. i want it to satay there when size is smaller and wwe can see it if we scroll left

Comment: does it still need `overflow:hidden;` ?

Comment: Nope, adding min-width of an acceptable value should show all of the elements so there is no overflow (thus it can be taken out)

Comment: @sam Anything else you're looking for?

Comment: If this problem is solved due to what I said, you can mark the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as correct. If you have another problem with your code that you're unable to solve through research, post another question about it here on SO